# Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop, runtime-error

I can't find a solution to my problem: I've done this for-loop but I don't know it keeps telling me : "Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : replacement has length zero".

```
for (i in 2:nrow(fp.adj)) {
  print(i)
  fp.adj[i,4]<-fp.adj[i,3]*fp.adj[i-1,4]
}
```

I'm working with a database with 2108 lines so it should be ok ... I can't figure out why ...
I've written `print(i)` just to check where it stops ... and it always stops at the first value of I ...

thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of the `fp.adj` data frame? The problem needs to be reproducible for other people on here to be able to provide a good and complete answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I ran this with created data (`fp.adj <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=25))`) and the loop completed. The problem seems likely to lie in your data, as @mysteRious suggests.